# What is the maximum number of rectangular blocks

Tags: volume

What is a simple way to solve this problem? I can do this problem by drawing the large block and trying small blocks, but very time consuming. I assume there must be a wise way to try the small blocks.

> What is the maximum number of rectangular blocks with dimensions 3 inches by 5 inches by 2 inches that will fit into a box 15 inches by 30 inches by 12 inches?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the volume of the large and small blocks. The dimensions have been chosen so you can show you can pack them perfectly, so just divide the volumes.